# What does 振り回して mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, verbs, conjugations, phrases

*I just started learning japanese a few months ago, and my japanese is a little basic, I can't understand some kanjis yet... Hope someone can help me... thanks!*

I was reading a manga, and while I was reading, a boy confessed his feelings to a girl, he said he liked her. But in the end, the girl is thinking:

> 振り回してやしないかと思ってたが。。。 振り回されてるのはこっちの方だった

And finally, the story ends there. I really couldn't understand what's the meaning of the sentence because I am struggling with the verb 振り回す.

I searched and saw that 振り回して is a form of 振り回す. But, I read many meanings of the verb (like "manipulate", "abuse", or "worry"...) and I don't know which one of them is the correct one here.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's your version? If you don't even make a try, this will be closed as offtopic (see http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-se/ )

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky My version? Sorry, I really don't know what 'version' are you talking about. And I already tried to understand the sentence, I searched in dictionaries, in forums, and more websites... but I couldn't understand what does "振り回して" means. Sorry if my question isn't allowed here.

Comment: I meant "your version of translation".  Here's a hint: `振り回して` is a form of `振り回す`.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Yeah, I searched and saw that 振り回して is a form of 振り回す. But, I read many meanings of the verb (like "manipulate", "abuse", or "worry"...) and I don't know which one of them is the correct one here. Sorry and thanks for your help :c

Comment: Hi, I suggested a major edit to your question to make it better suitable for this website. My Japanese isn't the best either otherwise I would add an answer too. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to involve someone into one's arbitrariness.

Answer (score 0):

振り回される means **to get pushed around**, to be swung. Swing is 振り回される too in English, but if human swing human, it's strange. So the speaker get pushed around.